# How to add path to link via script in Twig?

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, twig

I'm adding a script into my twig file, to redirect to other route.

```
<script>
$('#lnkPanel').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location = '{{ path('profile/' ~ user.id ~ '') }}';
});
```

But when my twig is rendering I get an error and this not show my  page. 
Error is: "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "profile/{1}" as such route does not exist.")"

How can I do to not get an error while is rendering twig, and show my page correctly??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SlimnViews `TwigExtension` you should be able to get it running like

```
<script>
$('#lnkPanel').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location = '{{ siteUrl('/profile/') }}{{user.id|e}}/';
});
</script>
```

Replace `{{user.id|e}}` with the Twig variable you have for user's profile ID.

Answer (score 0):

In the twig path function, it should be your route name :

```
window.location = '{{ path('profile_route_name', {id: user.id}) }}';
```

Comment: With this, I not get error while load page, but always the first element set the last id. Example: I need show 3 users. I have 3 ids. Only first element have the last id.  How can set the coresponding ids to the elements in twig??

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to do, but if it's a simple redirection you can in case your button are <a> tag : 

Add to your **href** attribute a {{path()}} with ids for each buttons.
Or if you are using <button> tag and click event :

Add a **data-id** attribute with the user id, and then in the event, fetch the id with :
    $(this).data("id");